# Linear systems matrix initial value

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear system (which I have attached)

find the solution $y(x)$ of the linear system that satisfies the initial value: $y(0) = n = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$ (column vector)

then find the solution of the non-homogeneous linear system $y' = Ay + (0 ,0, 2)$ satisfying the initial value $y(0) = n = (n_1, n_2, n_3) $

I've found the eigenvalues as lambda = 1, 2, 2

but I don't know how to continue. If someone could help me out, that would be good :)

[image]

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolutionsToSystems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Augment with the null-vector $(0,0,0)$.
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   3 & -1 & 1 & . & 0 \\
   2 & 0 & 1 & . & 0 \\
   1 & -1 & 2 & . & 0
   \end{bmatrix} \
   (r_1 \leftrightarrow r_3) \to
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -1 & 2 & . & 0 \\
   2 & 0 & 1 & . & 0 \\
   3 & -1 & 1 & . & 0
   \end{bmatrix} \
   $$
   $$
   (r_2-=2r_1,r_3-=3r_1)\to
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -1 & 2 & . & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & -3 & . & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & -5 & . & 0
   \end{bmatrix} \
   (r2/=2)\to
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -1 & 2 & . & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & \frac{-3}{2} & . & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & -5 & . & 0
   \end{bmatrix} \
   $$
   ...
2. Row-reduce -> this gives us the null-space of the matrix.
3. Augment with the particular solution $(0,0,2)$.
4. Add the two together gives us the solution.